# preg_replace specific Text to small latter strtolower

Tags: wordpress, function

Please i need to replace link with capital letter to small letter using wp function
E.g let every text after `/get/` be replace with small letter.

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/get/ASK-Question"> => <a href="https://stackexchange.com/get/ask-question">
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/get/aSK-QuesTion"> => <a href="https://stackexchange.com/get/ask-question">
```

here is my function, I dont know where i am getting it wrong. however i am not good in wp. please correct me by posting the full correct code.

```
function emailleftappend($content){

        $findleft = '/get\/(?<=\/)([A-Za-z]+?) ([A-Za-z]+?)(?=\/">)/m';
        $replaceleft = '$1-$2';
        $content = preg_replace(strtolower($findleft), $replaceleft, $content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'emailleftappend');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function emailleftappend($content){


    $content = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=get\/)(.*?)-(.*?)(?=\/">)/', function ($m) {
  return sanitize_title($m[1]). '-'. sanitize_title($m[2]); }, $content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'emailleftappend');
```

Finally fixed.